Java Program Cannot Locate CSV File in IntelliJ IDEA - FileNotFoundException
I’m working on a character recognition project using Java and IntelliJ IDEA. My program needs to load training and testing data from CSV files, but I’m encountering a FileNotFoundException even though the file paths appear to be correct.
Project Structure:
project-root/
  ├── .idea/
  ├── out/
  ├── src/
      ├── data/
          ├── mnist_test.csv
          ├── mnist_train.csv
      ├── layers/
      ├── network/
      └── Main.java
  └── README.md

Code snippet :
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting data loading.....");
        List<Image> imagesTest = new DataReader().readData("src/data/mnist_test.csv");
        List<Image> imagesTrain = new DataReader().readData("src/data/mnist_train.csv");

        System.out.println("Images Train size:" + imagesTrain.size());
        System.out.println("Images Test size :" + imagesTest.size());

        // Other code...
    }
}

DataReader class:
package data;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class DataReader {

    private final int rows = 28;
    private final int cols = 28;

    public List<Image> readData(String path) {
        List<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader dataReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = dataReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] lineItems = line.split(",");
                double[][] data = new double[rows][cols];
                int label = Integer.parseInt(lineItems[0]);
                int i = 1;
                for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
                    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
                        data[row][col] = (double) Integer.parseInt(lineItems[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                images.add(new Image(data, label));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not found " + path);
        }
        return images;
    }
}

Despite the files being in the correct directory (src/data/), I’m getting the following error:
Error Message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File not found src/data/mnist_test.csv
    at data.DataReader.readData(DataReader.java:62)
    at Main.main(Main.java:23)

What I've Tried:

I’ve double-checked that the CSV files are in the src/data/ directory.
I’ve made sure the file paths in my code are correct.
I’ve checked the working directory settings in IntelliJ IDEA, but I might be missing something.

I suspect the issue might be related to the working directory configuration in IntelliJ IDEA, but I’m not sure how to properly set it or if there’s another issue causing the program to be unable to locate the files.
How can I correctly configure IntelliJ IDEA or my code to ensure that the program can locate the mnist_test.csv and mnist_train.csv files?

File not found src/data/mnist_test.csv The path is relative to the working directory so I guess that project-root is not the working directory.

Have you considered using a standard maven/gradle project layout? Where java files are in src/main/java (tests in src/test/java) and resources are in src/main/resources (or src/test/resources) and resources can be accessed via a classloader instead of using file system?

Java is very particular, depending on the method you invoke, you may need for the path as: "/src/folder/file ‘ or else: ’src/folder/file ‘ or else: ’/folder/file ‘ or else: ’folder/file ”, play with the different paths until it works.

"throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not found " + path);" - replace this with throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not found " + path, e); and see what the exception's stack trace shows (and update it in the question).

In addition to all the useful comments above, you may find it useful to use new FileReader(new File(path).getAbsoluteFile()) and display your stacktrace as prasad_ advises above. Then you will see the full path of the file that it's looking for.

You are searching for nist_test.csv and mnist_train.csv inside project-root/src/data, however, the mistake you are doing is that you assume that you are executing the source, whereas, in actual reality you are executing the built project, that's likely located at project-root/out. So, you will need to make sure your data folder and the files inside are available inside your working directory, i.e., project-root/out.

It may be a permissions problem, try with an absolute path to check that this is not the problem.
If the code with absolute path works, you should use classpath paths for loading any files
 ClassLoader classLoader = Main.class.getClassLoader();
 URL resource = classLoader.getResource("data/mnist_test.csv");

